# Build search query from array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `Person` and a datatable `PersonCode`. Now in my controller, I want to make a search for multiple codes. What would be the right way to do this?

I tried to define a class method on `Person`

```
def self.code_filter(codes)
    joins(:PersonCode)
    codes.each do |code|
        where("rank > 1 AND person_code.code LIKE '%" + code +"%'")
end
```

But when I call this class method in my controller with, say ['Z','Q']

```
Person
    .code_filter(my_array)
    .another_query_method(some_value)
```

I get the the following error message: "undefined method `another_query_method' for ["Z", "Q"]:Array"

I kinda see why this isn't working but how can I make a correctly concatenated query with these SQL statements?

Comment: That is not a scope, that is a class method.

Comment: Ah I thought this is named the same way, sorry. I'll read the documentation again and edit the question.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930312/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-scopes-vs-class-methods

Comment: Just another think, if you need [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) you must implement a `scope` because it return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `each` method.

This method returns the original Array object.

```
[1,2,3].each {|i| p i + 1}
```

returns [1,2,3].

Use [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and you'll get an array of relations

Comment: But doesn't map return an array object as well while I should have ActiveRecord::Relation as return value?