# Am I using a scope method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

In my movie model, I have the following code.

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
  validates :title, :description, :movie_length, :director, :rating, presence: true
end
 

def self.show_order_desc
  self.review.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

And I'm calling this in my movie controller show action where I have my reviews for that movie.

```
 def show
     @reviews = show_order_desc
 end
```

is this the right way? is this a scope? it's working but I have a review coming along and I want to be sure to past this feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord scopes vs class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930312/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-scopes-vs-class-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to fetch all reviews of a movie in descending order of `created_at`. You can follow bellow codes.

```
# app/models/movie.rb

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :reviews

  validates :title, :description, :movie_length, :director, :rating, presence: true
end
```

```
# app/models/review.rb

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user

  scope :created_desc, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

```
# app/controllers/movies_controller.rb

class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_movie, only: [:show] # you can add other actions also

  def show
    @reviews = @movie.reviews.created_desc
  end

  # your other actoins

  private

  def find_movie
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here I have added one scope in `Review` model which will order reviews as per your requirement. Now in the `show` action I am fetching reviews of a movie first, then using the scope for against those reviews to order in descending order with `created_at`.